# Unirest post request body

Tags: node.js, express, http, post, unirest

I want to be able to send data from one server to another, started on the same device (to start with). I have this:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
const urlEncodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false});
app.post('/test', urlEncodedParser, (request, response) =>
{
    console.log(request.body);
});
app.listen(9999);
console.log('Server started on port 9999');

const unirest = require('unirest');
unirest.post('http://127.0.0.1:9999/test').headers({'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}).send({"test1": 123321, "test2": "321123"})
.then((response) => 
{
    console.log(response.body);
});
```

It looks logical, but `console.log(request.body);` gives empty object {} yet in the post requests I do send some data using .send. How to get access to that data in the request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are sending data with `Content-Type: 'application/json'`, so on the server you need to connect middleware not for `urlencoded`, but for `json`. In addition, you do not need to separately connect the `body-parser` since it is included in `express` and you can connect the necessary middleware like this:

Server:

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

app.post('/test', express.json(), (request, response) => {
    console.log(request.body);
    response.end('OK');
});

app.listen(9999, () => console.log('Server started on port 9999'));
```

Client:

```
const unirest = require('unirest');

unirest
    .post('http://127.0.0.1:9999/test')
    .headers({ Accept: 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
    .send({ test1: 123321, test2: '321123' })
    .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.body);
    });
```